# Saving file into another file using VBScript after modification

Tags: vbscript

I have some XML files in a folder `\\demo.US\Modified\`. The files in the folder are:

```
USA.xml
Canada.xml
Mexico.xml
```

The code below is changing the encoding from UTF-8 to windows-1252 and is creating a modified file `mod.xml`.

This `mod.xml` file have data from all three XML files concatenated.

I need help so I can save files separately.

If value of `objFile.Name` is `USA.xml` then it should save modified file name as `USA_mod.xml`. the output for `\\demo.US\Modified\` folder after execution is complete should have mod files in it as below.

```
USA.xml
Canada.xml
Mexico.xml
USA_mod.xml
Canada_mod.xml
Mexico_mod.xml
```

The code I used is as follows.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

objStartFolder = "\\demo.US\Modified\"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile In colFiles
    WScript.Echo objFile.Name

    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objStartFolder & objFile.Name, 1)
    Set outFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objStartFolder & "mod.xml", 2, True)

    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
        strContent = strContent & objFile.ReadLine
    Loop
    MsgBox strContent
    strContent = Replace(strContent, "encoding=""UTF-8""", "encoding=""windows-1252""")
    outFile.WriteLine strContent
    outFile.Close
    objFile.Close
Next
```

Comment: You can't change the encoding of a file by doing some string replacement. On top of that, vanilla VBScript does not have the ability to do what you want. There is no valid reason to ever want to change the encoding of XML files, unless you are not processing them properly. If that's the case, change the processing code, not the files.

Comment: These XML files are used in Qlikview for some visualization purpose, there are some special characters appearing in the files that is causing an issue. file loads fine when encoding is changed to windows-1252,,,,this is the reason i am changing encoding from UTF-8 to windows-1252

Comment: What I mean by that: There is not a single XML parser *in the world* that cannot handle UTF-8 endcoded XML files. Not one. Your wish to change the file encoding can only mean that you are planning to process the files with something other than an XML parser. And you should not do that. (And I'm not even getting into the fact that UTF-8 can contain characters that cannot even exist in Windows-1252.)

Comment: Qlikview is giving an issue with UTF-8 encoding..Error is "An invalid character was found in text Content" but when I replace the line encoding="UTF-8" in xml file  to encoding="windows-1252"   I am able to load the data into Qlikview.

Comment: @mb1987 maybe you should change the question to something like "I'm getting error xxx when processing and XML file in UTF-8. Here's a sample of the data that's causing the error. I've tried handling it by changing encoding, but that doesn't seem right. How do I fix this?"

Comment: That is ominous. Does the unchanged file open properly in a different tool? Internet Explorer is a good canary for XML files - if it opens correctly there, the file is fine, if not, the XML file is broken and you'd have to take a sharp look at whoever produces these files.

Comment: @FreeMan I am able to change the encoding but when saving the file,  all the data goes into one single file "mod.xml"...which I don't want.  this is the reason I asked the question

Comment: @Tomalak  unchanged files is giving issue in internet explorer too...  Notepad ++ also gives this error  .... XML Parsing error at line 46:  Input is not proper UTF-8, Indicating encoding! Bytes: 0xA0 0x4B 0x65 0x69

Comment: Then the files are not actually UTF-8. How are they produced?

Comment: @mb1987 my bad, I didn't phrase that well. It sounds like you should be asking "A character in this UTF-8 encoded XML file line is being reported as invalid. Which one and why?". It seems you know the line of the file...

Comment: @Tomalak  they are in UTF-8  there are about 5000 files in the folder only 1 or 2 files gives an issue sometimes. ,,,,,There files are produced by an ETL job , and placed in a folder on server

Comment: @FreeMan what I need help is in the modification of the code I am working with. characters can be different in future files , all i need some expert help is saving the file right now  ..endocing issue is resolved when I changed it to windows-1252

Comment: Then the ETL job has a bug that should probably be looked into, to fix the problem at the source, rather than bend over backwards to fix the symptoms.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon ETL task is done by someone else, I am not able to contact the person as he is in different timezone, and possibly it will take them some time to fix this on their end. the quick fix is to change encoding to  windows-1252

Comment: Sure. And then risk breaking something else in the process. Have fun!

Comment: I'm flummoxed by how "a different timezone" is an impediment to contacting someone in this electronic age. You realize that when it's 15:00(UTC-5) for me, someone else could be answering/commenting on this post at 01:00(UTC+5), 'cause they're a night owl or work a night shift? They might even see it the next morning...

Comment: @FreeMan  My friend I need help in fixing the code right now which I am working on. for some one else to fix ETL job on their end will take atleast a week time through change request. my stake holders can't wait that long, that's why for now changing Encoding is a quick fix.

Comment: We are telling you that any plan is better than yours. You're making excuses. What you plan to do will not help you in the short run an will make things worse in the long run. Your stakeholders can wait for a week, especially when the situation is not your fault. I know, because I've had stakeholders.

Comment: @Tomalak I am not changing encoding of all 5000+ files , only files that is causing an issue, I have a Qlikview trigger that executes everyday and refreshes the dashboard, for now I just need help in this code.  So Qlikview can able to load the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to made it working, below is the code I used

```
Dim objFSO, filePath, objFile, colFiles, s , FName
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set filePath = objFSO.GetFolder("\\demo.US\Modified\")
Set colFiles = filePath.Files

For Each FName in colFiles

set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FName.Path,1)
set outFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(LEFT(FName.Path,instr(FName.Path,".xml")-1) &"_mod.xml",2,True)

do until objFile.AtEndOfStream
strContent=objFile.ReadLine
Loop
strContent = Replace(strContent, "encoding=""UTF-8""", "encoding=""windows-1252""") 
outFile.WriteLine strContent
outFile.Close
objFile.Close  
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have already pointed out, you shouldn't do what you're attempting to do here, because it is very likely to create more problems down the road. Find the cause of the issue and fix that instead of trying to handle symptoms. You have been warned.

With that said, the reason why the content of all input files is written to the same output file is because you always specify the same output file. That file should contain only the content of the last input file, though, because you open the file for writing (thus erasing previous content) rather than for appending.

Replace these lines:

```
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objStartFolder & objFile.Name, 1)
Set outFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objStartFolder & "mod.xml", 2, True)
```

with this:

```
Set inFile = objFile.OpenAsTextStream
outFilename = objFSO.BuildPath(objStartFolder, objFSO.GetBaseName(objFile) & "_mod.xml")
Set outFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(outFilename, 2, True)
```

and also replace the other occurrences of `objFile` after that with `inFile` (*always* avoid changing the value of a loop variable), and the code should do what you expect it to do. But again, be warned that the output may not be valid XML.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, Thanks for your input,  I tried modifying the code but it is giving an error  : 
           Type mismatch objFSO.GetBaseName CODE: 800A000D

Comment: @mb1987 I missed that you were replacing the file object in the loop variable with the text stream from opening that file. Never do that. Always use a different variable.